# Full screen application turns to windowed application and leaves a black screen in Mission Control

Tags: macos, big-sur, mission-control

While I'm working, I often see an application I made full screen turn to a windowed mode. When I attempt to make it full screen again, it leaves a black screen in my Mission Control. I've attached an image below. Has anyone else experienced this and do y'all have any solutions?

[image: full screen app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a temporary solution: This happens on Big Sur when applications open pop-ups as tabs in full screen mode. Closing those tabs seemed to have caused the issue as far as I am currently aware.

To fix this currently, I went to System Preferences > General > Prefer Tabs: "never"

This also fixes JetBrains IDEs (PHP Storm, Android Studio, PyCharm, IntelliJ IDEA, etc) becoming unresponsive with pop ups. After I found a solution to that issue I was having, it seemed to fix applications in full screen like Firefox and XCode having the primary issue I inquired about above.